# What kind of barcode is this? It's not a standard UPC or EAN... so what is it? Some Chinese proprietary?

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner

Can't seem to scan it with an known iOS barcode scanning SDK:

[image]

Comment: How do you know it is a valid barcode?

Comment: I don't, I can only assume it is because it's on what looks to be some kind of official packaging... but from Hong Kong you never know. Just looking to see if anyone out there has run across this before.

Comment: Looks sorta like MSI (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSI_Barcode), but could be custom. It is definitely not UPC, Code 39, Code 128 or I2of5.

Comment: Seems like EAN-12 barcode type